# Trying to get SQL to give me a static total no matter the date range

Tags: sql, sum

The problem I'm working with is in regards to payments which occur outside of the where clause.

If I have 2 payments made, on on 10/1/2020 and another on 10/20/2020 for $20 each, I need to see a total paid of $40. However, the amount is changing based off the date filter.

If I choose 10/1-10/20 it'll show the total paid as 40 but if I do 10/15-10/20 then it'll only show 20.  I have 3 columns called Bill, Total Paid, amount paid on date. The total paid is the one that should remain stagnant

Example query

```
Select b.name as bill, bp.amount as 'amount paid'
from bill b 
left join billpayment bp on b.id=bp.bill_id
where bp.date between Startdate and Enddate
```

So that gives me the payments but I would like it to add up any payments that occurred outside the date range.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the overall total, use window functions in a subquery:

```
select bp.*
from (Select b.name as bill, bp.amount as amount_paid,
             sum(bp.amount) over () as total_amount
      from bill b left join
           billpayment bp
           on b.id = bp.bill_id
     ) bp
where bp.date between Startdate and Enddate
```

Comment: So I'm running the above but getting a "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() " error when running. I've tried playing around with the wording but still can't get it to process. Using SEQUEL PRO for reference.